# Capybara Selenium Firefox untrusted issuer screen

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Is there a way to bypass the untrusted issuer screen that appears on Firefox?  I'm struggling to follow with geckodriver etc.  It's changed a lot since the last time I needed Firefox in Selenium.

My env file has the following:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  opts = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
  opts.add_argument('acceptInsecureCerts')
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :firefox, options: opts)
end

Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
```

I'm using Firefox 54
selenium webdriver 3.4.3
geckodriver 0.17

I think I'm using options wrong but I can't find the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `accept_insecure_certs` in the desired capabilities.  The following should do it for you

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.new(accept_insecure_certs: true)
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :firefox,
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
end
```

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you.  Is there an online reference to these capabilities? My searches didn't return much.  Thanks again

Comment: @Tom The whole capabilities/options API is in flux in Selenium (and has been for a while), I generally find it easiest to just check the source code - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c/capabilities.rb#L45